# Beginner While loop error in MySQL

Tags: mysql, loops, while-loop

I have looked at various guides on MySQL WHILE Loops and still can't figure out what I am doing wrong.

```
mysql> DELIMITER $$
mysql> CREATE PROCEDURE insertRooms()
-> BEGIN
-> DECLARE nRoom INT DEFAULT 101;
-> WHILE nRoom < 109 DO
-> INSERT INTO simple_room (room_number) VALUES nRoom;
-> SET nRoom = nRoom + 1;
-> END WHILE;
-> END;
-> $$
ERROR 1064 (42000): You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that
corresponds to your MySQL server version for the right syntax to use near 'nRoom
;
SET nRoom = nRoom + 1;
END WHILE;
END' at line 5
```

I am simply trying to do a while loop that will insert rooms 101 - 108 into the simple_room table. All help is appreciated, I have tried searching all over Google and Stackoverflow and could not find why I keep getting a syntax error. I am using MySQL version 5.6.24.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your query is all correct except you forgot using brackets around `nRomm`. Try this,

```
mysql> DELIMITER $$
mysql> CREATE PROCEDURE insertRooms()
-> BEGIN
-> DECLARE nRoom INT DEFAULT 101;
-> WHILE nRoom < 109 DO
-> INSERT INTO simple_room (room_number) VALUES(nRoom);
-> SET nRoom = nRoom + 1;
-> END WHILE;
-> END;
-> $$
```

Hope it helps, thanks.